# Unity3D animation by transparency option

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, transparency

I am developing a small project by Unity3D. In project there are some keys. when I click a key the key's transparency will be smoothly change to 50% to 100% and this change will take 0.5 sec. So I need animation of the option transparency. Is it possible in Unity3D to smoothly animate of a object's transparency?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried making a unity animation?

Answer (score 3):

You should [Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) inside the `Update` loop to change the color. Use the `Time` class to measure time. Check the `Lerp` documentation for an example.

I also found this code, it changes the transparency using `Lerp` but not exactly the way you want, and it's *unityscript*, unfortunately:

```
#pragma strict

var duration : float = 1.0;
var alpha : float = 0;

function Update(){

lerpAlpha();
}

function lerpAlpha () {

var lerp : float = Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;

alpha = Mathf.Lerp(0.0, 1.0, lerp) ;
renderer.material.color.a = alpha;
}
```

---

UPDATE

The answer above is still valid but I want to recommend using [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com), a free plugin with option to go pro that does all sorts of lerps - color, positions, rotations, alpha, etc. It's really easy to use, have good performance and I've been using it in multiple projects.

Answer (score 2):

if your script is a c# script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WebPlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool selected = false;
    //Setting the colors like this, you can change them via inspector
    public Color enabledColor = new Color(1,1,1,1);
    public Color disabledColor = new Color(1,1,1,0.5f);
    public float transitionTime = 0.5f;
    private float lerp = 0;

    void Start(){
        lerp = selected ? 1 : 0;
    }
    //You can set by this method the button state! :)
    public void SetSelected(bool isSelected){
        selected = isSelected;
    }
    void Update(){
        lerp += (isSelected ? 1 : -1) * Time.deltaTime/transitionTime;
        lerp = Mathf.Clamp01 (lerp);
        renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(disabledColor,enabledColor,lerp);
    }
}
```